# Question about tensor operators

Tags: tensor-calculus

I have learned there is a so called tensor product in linear algebra when one is trying to pair vectors (or operators) from two different vector spaces, they use the symbol $\otimes$. But then in QM I also heard about tensor operators, which include the rotation operator. In its discussion, one usually also talks about the (ir)reducible representation. However, in this matter I don't see how these tensor operators connect to the tensor product to pair two different vectors.

Please someone explain to me what's the connection between the two "tensors" used in these two seemingly separate subjects. Also I would like to know which book I can read up about tensor operators and its algebra.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? It seems to me e.g. the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_operator) is sufficient to understand what a "tensor operator" is.